# How to loop writer .csv?

Tags: java, android

I want every data to be retrieved once looping will occur in the CSV writer, how do I make the loop occur?

thanks!

[Data from Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ6Zm.png)

[Output writer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoYZC.jpg)

*sorry, i can't display images 'cause it must have 10 reputations :(

```
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/StockCount/");

        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }

        File myCSV = new File(root, currentDate + " DataStockCount.csv");
        myCSV.createNewFile();

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(myCSV);
        writer.append("Date : " + getDate + "\n");
        writer.append("Inspector : " + getInspector + "\n");
        writer.append("Location : " + getLocation + "\n");
        writer.append("Product Name : " + getProductName + "\n");
        writer.append("Price : " + getPrice + "\n");
        writer.append("Quantity : " + getAmount + "\n");
        writer.append("Barcode : " + getCode + "\n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, "File Saved Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Retrieved how, where? Your question is quite unclear, can you write an example output of what you're expecting?

Comment: @cardouken sorry, question edited..

Answer (score 0):

Why not using an existing library like [FastCSV](https://github.com/osiegmar/FastCSV)?

Comment: thanks for your answer. finally, i'm using opencsv library